# Derivation for full conditional distribution?

Tags: distributions, bayesian

I'm a biochem grad student trying to understand part of my research group's math. Could someone help me understand the derivation for a full conditional distribution for the *i*-th individual mean, which is given by $$\alpha_i|y,\mu_\alpha, \alpha_{k_\ne}{_i}, \sigma_y, \sigma_\alpha \sim N(m,v)$$
Where $$v=(n_i/\sigma^2_y+1/\sigma^2_\alpha)^{-1}  $$
$$m=v\times(n_i/\sigma^2_y\times\bar{y}_i + 1/\sigma^2_\alpha\times\mu_\alpha) = (n_i/\sigma^2_y\times\bar{y}_i + 1/\sigma^2_\alpha\times\mu_\alpha)/(n_i/\sigma^2_y+1/\sigma^2_\alpha)$$

Understood by the Bayesian rule $$p(\alpha_i|y,\mu_\alpha,\alpha_{k\ne}{_i}, \sigma_y,\sigma_\alpha)\propto(y|\alpha_i,\alpha_{k\ne}{_i}, \sigma_y)p(\alpha_i|\mu_\alpha,\sigma_\alpha)$$

Comment: Without further details, you question has not as we do not know what the prior and the likelihood are, even though we can guess. Please add `self-study` to your tags.